# SAPUI5 suspend / resume oData binding not triggering

Tags: odata, sapui5

I need to setup oData binding in a view so that, by default the items aggregation of a table (containing products) is 'suspended' until I click a button that 'resumes' the binding and loads in the products.

Example is here UI5 Tips: Use of Binding Suspend | SAP Blogs but when I try to apply this to the items aggregation of a table, the resume() does nothing, and no products are shown.

```
 <Table id="productsTable"
     items="{path: 'Products', suspended: true }"

 onProductSearchAll: function (oEvent) {
                    const oView = this.getView();
                    const table = oView.byId("productsTable");
                    const binding = table.getBinding("items");
                    binding.resume();
```

}
For now, the workaround has been to NOT include the items aggregation in the view, and to unbind/bind the items aggregation in the controller.

This is a more cumbersome solution, so would be good to confirm why the cleaner suspend/resume solution fails in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

[Aggregation binding info](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.AggregationBindingInfo) property `suspended` works regardless whether the binding `path` is relative or absolute, and on all subclasses of `ListBinding` such as the `v2.ODataListBinding`, `v4.ODataListBinding`, `JSONListBinding`<sup>1</sup> **unless documented otherwise.<sup>2</sup>**

If you'd like the framework to fetch the entities via aggregation binding declaratively but with it being suspended initially:

1. Double-check whether the binding is really an instance of `ODataListBinding` (E.g. via `this.byId("productsTable").getBinding("items").getMetadata().getName()`).
2. Ensure that the binding `path` is actually correct in the first place.

   ```xml
   <Table id="productsTable" items="{
     path: 'myODataModel>validRelativeOrAbsolutePath',
     suspended: true,
     templateShareable: false,
     ...: ...
   }">
   ```

If everything is correct, the framework (not any controller code) will fetch the entities automatically for you if `suspended` is undefined or `false`. With `suspended: true`, the request will be sent first when the application calls `this.byId("productsTable").getBinding("items").resume()` explicitly.

**Sample:** [embed.plnkr.co/65HoSzWHdPnCzZZc](https://embed.plnkr.co/65HoSzWHdPnCzZZc?show=view%2FHome.view.xml,preview:%3Fsap-ui-xx-componentPreload%3Doff)

---

<sup>1</sup> Although `suspended: true` is technically supported by `JSONListBinding`, in contrast to server-side models such as the V2 and V4 `ODataModel`s, the `JSONModel` is a client-side model where the data are fed by the application code manually. Hence, the use-case of `suspended: true` in `JSONListBinding` is limited compared to server-side list bindings.

<sup>2</sup> Currently known limitations are:

- Documented in the OData V4 topic ["Suspend and Resume"](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/b0f5c531e5034a27952cc748954cbe39). See also the "Throws" information at [`sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding#suspend`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataListBinding#methods/suspend) to learn in which cases an actual `Error` is thrown.
- Subclasses of `TreeBinding` do not support `suspended` yet. Cf. [OpenUI5 issue #3161](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/3161).